# Issue with 3d input to CNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

My code looks like this:

```
sys.path.append('..')
from utils import *

import argparse
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
from torch.autograd import Variable

class ChessNNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, game, args):
        # game params
        self.board_x, self.board_y, self.board_z = game.getBoardSize()  # 8, 8, 12
        self.action_size = game.getActionSize()  # 64 * 64 = 4096
        self.args = args

        super(ChessNNet, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(self.board_z, args.num_channels, 3, stride=1, padding=1)  # num_channels = 512
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(args.num_channels, args.num_channels, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(args.num_channels, args.num_channels, 3, stride=1)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(args.num_channels, args.num_channels, 3, stride=1)

        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(args.num_channels)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(args.num_channels)
        self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(args.num_channels)
        self.bn4 = nn.BatchNorm2d(args.num_channels)

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(args.num_channels*(self.board_x-4)*(self.board_y-4), 1024)
        self.fc_bn1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(1024)

        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1024, 512)
        self.fc_bn2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(512)

        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(512, self.action_size)

        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(512, 1)

    def forward(self, s):
        #                                                           s: batch_size x board_x x board_y
        s = s.view(-1, self.board_z, self.board_x, self.board_y)                # batch_size x 1 x board_x x board_y Rectified Linear Activation Function
        s = F.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(s)))                          # batch_size x num_channels x board_x x board_y
        s = F.relu(self.bn2(self.conv2(s)))                          # batch_size x num_channels x board_x x board_y
        s = F.relu(self.bn3(self.conv3(s)))                          # batch_size x num_channels x (board_x-2) x (board_y-2)
        s = F.relu(self.bn4(self.conv4(s)))                          # batch_size x num_channels x (board_x-4) x (board_y-4)
        s = s.view(-1, self.args.num_channels*(self.board_x-4)*(self.board_y-4))

        # dropout = 0.3
        s = F.dropout(F.relu(self.fc_bn1(self.fc1(s))), p=self.args.dropout, training=self.training)  # batch_size x 1024
        s = F.dropout(F.relu(self.fc_bn2(self.fc2(s))), p=self.args.dropout, training=self.training)  # batch_size x 512

        pi = self.fc3(s)                                                                         # batch_size x action_size
        v = self.fc4(s)                                                                          # batch_size x 1

        return F.log_softmax(pi, dim=1), torch.tanh(v)
```

The code is runnable. However, I am not sure whether there is an issue or not, as my prediction is not accurate enough. I do training process for multiple hours, after that loss function starts to get something like 2.0, and does not get bellow anymore. Not sure if I inicialize first conv1 layer correctly, using in_channels = self.board_z (12)

My input to forward functions is chessboard - so 8 x 8 (amount of squares) x 12 (type of piece)
In the most inside array, there is only one 1 value, rest of them are zeros.
Example:

```
[ - columns
    [ - rows
        [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0] - one square
        [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
        [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
        [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
    ]
    [
        [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0] - one square
        [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
        [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
        [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
    ]
    ...
]
```

I am not sure how to tell my CNN that I am not giving it 2d array, but 3d array (as every element of 2d array contains 12 values)
It is possible?

Just to mention, the purpose of the network is that I give game board as input, and expect array of move possibilities (1d, 4096)

Please tell me what is wrong with my net. Thank you

Comment: It seems that coordinates are more important than values. In such a case, CNN is not effective. So first, see what happens if you don't use Conv2d and use only Linear layers (and BN and Relu). Also, for your task, I recommend that you start with a larger number of channels/layers, since it won't be a problem even if your model memorizes the whole thing. Another thing that might help is to start with a smaller board and a smaller variety of pieces. If you try only pawn moves on a 3x3 board and if it still doesn't work, there is definitely a bug in your code.